# Page Tab Banner missing "Page History" and other buttons

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon, version-history

We have a SharePoint 2016 test site with several sub-sites.

The homepage for some of our sub-sites have the following Page Tab Banner:

[image]

While other sub-sites have the below much more restrictive Page Tab Banner:

[image]

What is happening here? Why does the above banner not have a page history button? Is it a permissions issue? I should have full control to the site and this sub-site... Any assistance you can provide would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT1:** Thank you for the responses. I cannot reply to them (Need 50 Rep), so I will reply below.

- **vinit kumar** - Both sites have the same features enabled.
- **Sohail Shaikh** - Is it possible to convert a Web Part Page into a Wiki Page?
- **Tally** - I checked the Advanced Permissions for both sites and when I typed my name it said that I have "Full Control" to each of
  them.

**EDIT2:** I think Sohail Shaikh's answer is what I needed to understand - The first banner is for a Wiki Page and the second is for a Web Part Page.

I activated a "Wiki Page Home Page" and the new homepage had the more advanced Page Banner.

*Site Settings -> Site Actions -> Manage Site Features -> Wiki Page Home Page -> Activate.*

You can access the old homepage from the Site Structure:

*Site Settings -> Site Administration -> Content and structure*

In my case, the old Web Part homepage was called "default" and the new Wiki homepage had been placed in the "Site Pages" folder.

Comment: Please check all the features Enabled is same in both the sub sites and check both the Page Library Advance settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below page toolbar refers to **Wiki Page**.

[image]

Below page toolbar refers to **Web Part Page**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have different permissions in each site/sub-site.

Regarding the Page History / Versioning - it might be that in Site A versioning is enabled, whereas in Site B versioning is not in use, therefore there is no version history available.